# Need to sum rows of data across multiple columns of variables using dplyr

Tags: r

Others have asked similar questions, but their data structure was a bit different. My data set has multiple columns for both grouping variables and numeric data. I need to sum the numeric data per row and output the sum to a new data column. See example `DATA` set and the desired `RESULTS` tables below. I prefer to find a solution using the `mutate` function in `dplyr`. I primary use the `dplyr` package to manipulate my data sets. I can accomplish this task via `gather`, `group_by`, and `sumarise` functions in `dplyr`, but I am working with very large data sets which can cause “gathered” data tables to be in excess of 2,000,000 rows.  Thanks in advance.

```
DATA = data.frame(SITE = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"), 
                  DATE = c("1","1","2","2","3","3","3","4","4"), 
                  STUFF = c(1, 2, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 5000, 6000),
                  STUFF2 = c(2, 4, 60, 80, 200, 400, 600, 10000, 12000))

RESULT = data.frame(SITE = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"), 
                    DATE = c("1","1","2","2","3","3","3","4","4"), 
                    STUFF = c(1, 2, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 5000, 6000),
                    STUFF2 = c(2, 4, 60, 80, 200, 400, 600, 10000, 12000),
                    SUM_STUFF = c(3, 6, 90, 120, 300, 600, 900, 15000, 18000))
```

Comment: If you employ dplyr, `mutate(DATA, SUM_STUFF = rowSums(DATA[,3:4]))` would be one way, I think.

Comment: ... or the only-slightly-faster (but base-R) `within(DATA, { SUMS=rowSums(DATA[,3:4]) })`.

Comment: ... or the more-generic `within(DATA, { SUMS=rowSums(DATA[,sapply(DATA, is.numeric)]) })`, which will sum ***all*** numeric columns ... a bit drastic, but no magic constants!

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it meets your needs:

```
RESULT <- DATA %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(SUM_STUFF = sum(STUFF,STUFF2))
```

The key is to use `rowwise` (which may have been added to to a version of `dplyr` after you asked your question).

```
> RESULT
Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
Groups: <by row>

    SITE   DATE STUFF STUFF2 SUM_STUFF
  (fctr) (fctr) (dbl)  (dbl)     (dbl)
1      A      1     1      2         3
2      A      1     2      4         6
3      A      2    30     60        90
4      A      2    40     80       120
5      B      3   100    200       300
6      B      3   200    400       600
7      B      3   300    600       900
8      C      4  5000  10000     15000
9      C      4  6000  12000     18000
```